# How to edit navigation in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to edit the navigation in wordpress. I went to the Page editor and it seems that the navigation and footer is separate from the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit menus in the Appearance > Menus